# Setting the month August on datepicker in Xamarin UITest

Tags: android, xamarin, read-eval-print-loop, ui-testing, xamarin.uitest

I am creating some automated tests for an android app using Xamarin UITest and I have come to an issue specifically entering the month "Aug" (August) into a number picker input of the date.

Using REPL(), I have the below:

```
app.EnterText(x=>x.Id("month"), "Aug")
```

When doing this, the result on screen is "Apr" and it looks like just by typing the letter "A", the month automatically presumes "Apr".

the tree view is the following:

[image]

Can anyone please assist? How do I set the month August on a number picker input?

Answer (score 1):

The internal value of the `NumberPicker` is a number, so invoke the "setValue" method of the widget and assign it the "month" that you need:

```
app.Query(x=>x.Id("month").Invoke("setValue", 7));
```

Note: When using `Invoke`, use the Java method name, not the C# one.

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover,
I have just tried your solution and although it does set the month to August, it doesn't retain this value when leaving the NumberPicker screen. It seems to default back to the original state it was in.